# how to make a non-rouded corner line bottom of input bar

Tags: html, css

I'm make fluent style input bar
and this is my progress [image]

But, I want its line don't have rounded corner and it change its height when focus on it (it move the layout)

How can I do?

This is my code↓

```css
body {
  background-color: #1a2228;
}

input {
  background: #272f36;
  border: 1px solid #282d31;
  border-radius: 3px;
  width: 10em;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #979a9e;
  padding-left: 5px;
  transition: 200ms;
}

input::placeholder {
  color: #aeaeae;
  transition: 200ms;
}

input:hover {
  transition: 200ms;
  background: #2d343b;
}

input:focus {
  background: #1d1f21;
  transition: 200ms;
  border-bottom: 2px #4cc2ff solid;
}

input:focus::placeholder {
  color: #959697;
}

input[type="number"]::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
  cursor: pointer;
}

input[type="number"]::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input[type="number"]::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}
```

```html
<input id="a" type="number" min="0" max="100" placeholder="test">
```

[image]

no rounded corner bottom, like microsoft fluent design

Comment: You might need to try using the `::after` pseudo-element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option A: Drawing the border with the input background.

From https://ericfortis.github.io/web-tricks/#-css-mui-input-animation

```css
.myinput {
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  border-radius: 3px;
  outline: 0;
  background-size: 0 1px;
  background-color: transparent;
  background-image: linear-gradient(dodgerblue 0%, dodgerblue 100%);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: bottom -1px center;
}

.myinput:focus {
  background-size: 100% 2px;
}
```

```html
<input class="myinput">
```

---

Option B:

The trick is using two wrappers, the outermost for containing the border radius for the edges effect, the inner wrapper for an actual straight line.

```css
body {
  background-color: #1a2228;
}

.myinput {
  border: 1px solid #484d31;
  width: 10em;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.myinput:has(input:focus) {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #4cc2ff;
}

.myinput input {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: #272f36;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #979a9e;
  width: 100%;
  border: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="myinput">
  <div>
    <input>
  </div>
</div>
```